# Will followers drown?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If you have Waterbreathing, but your follower does not, will they follow you into deep water and stay down long enough to drown themselves?

I may play-test this myself in the next few days, but I was wondering if anyone else might already know the answer.  In any case, I figured it would be good to have this question here for anyone else that might be interested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can NPCs drown?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82596/can-npcs-drown) (I know that this question is older, but the other question is more general and also covers followers.)

Comment: I don't like older questions getting closed as dupes of newer ones...

Comment: @galacticninja By your logic, the question you've linked would then be closed by a question like [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95254/can-npcs-and-non-aquatic-creatures-drown) if it were to be asked about [tag:skyrim], and (more so for other topics than this) we could go on ad nauseum.  Where a narrower question precedes a more general question, I consider them *related* - not duplicate - and would not close either.

Comment: @Iszi No. That [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95254/can-npcs-and-non-aquatic-creatures-drown) (of mine) is not about Skyrim. This question and [Can NPCs drown?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82596/can-npcs-drown) are about the same game.

Comment: @galacticninja I didn't say it was about Skyrim.  I was proposing a hypothetical scenario where someone *did* ask that question for Skyrim.

Comment: @jmfsg Is it a policy or just a matter of preference (older questions should not be getting closed as dupes of newer ones)? If it's policy, then I made a mistake.

Comment: @Iszi It's not similar to this question, though. In this case, all followers *are* NPCs. So this [skyrim] question is fully covered by [Can NPCs drown?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/82596/4797). Where in that other [oblivion] question (of mine), it's about NPCs *and* [non-aquatic creatures](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95254/can-npcs-and-non-aquatic-creatures-drown).  So, no, it *probably won't* be closed as a duplicate. (I wouldn't word that question to include NPCs, if it's tagged [skyrim] though, as that part is already covered by the question, *Can NPCs drown?*

Comment: @galacticninja This question was asked eight months before the proposed duplicate. If anything, this one should remain open.

Comment: @Iszi Please don't take my close vote as an attack on this question (or you). I think this is a useful question. But I had to vote to close it since I think it's already better covered by the other one. Also, there's the case of the policy regarding closing older question as duplicates (what I asked to jmfsg).

Comment: @jmfsg I've proposed a duplicate on the newer question, and it looks like it will be closed. Perhaps an answer merge? I don't think it would be necessary since we don't delete dupes, though.....

Comment: @Fluttershy Merging's a good idea. How do we propose a merge? Should we flag this question?

Comment: @galacticninja I think you may need to question two policies here (which may require digging through and/or posting on [meta.gaming.se] or [meta.se]):  1. Is there a particular policy regarding closing older questions as dupes of newer ones?  2. What defines a "related" question as opposed to "duplicate"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They won't drown. I've down hours underwater with a mask that has waterbreathing enchantments, followers (companions and otherwise) will swim near/around you and will not drown.

Comment: Same logic applies when you jump down from a mountain in dangerous path - you might get hurt or die from falling but your follower will keep looking for safe way down.

Comment: Do you remember specifically which followers you tried this with?  Are you sure they weren't essentials?

Comment: Yep. I did this with both Lydia and Aela.