# Can NPCs drown?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will followers drown?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48812/will-followers-drown)

Is it possible to drown a guard in a pool of water? Say, for instance, I am an Argonian and I just killed someone in Whiterun. I then lure the guard that is chasing me into the pool at Dragonsreach. I go underwater and he goes also. After a while, will this guard drown like the player can?

Comment: I don't think NPCs drown.  I've had several Forsworn following me around underwater while I was wearing the Volsung mask and they floated around me forever.  FYI, I was waiting underwater while I waited for a random dragon to take out as many Forsworn as it could before I came up to finish the job.  I was too weak, you see.

Comment: Not all NPCs are followers. However, *all* followers are NPCs. Why then, was this question closed as an 'exact duplicate' of "[Will followers drown?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48812/will-followers-drown)" It should be the other way around. This question fully covers that question, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 8):

No, NPCs never take drowning damage. They'll try to come up for air every now and again, but nothing will happen if they can't reach the surface.

Answer (score 2):

NPC's wont drown. I had a dismissed follower stuck in the moat outside Dragonsreach for days and she was fine.

Comment: Any particular follower?  Some are considered essential by the game, and cannot die.

Comment: This was Jenassa. She can die, but she didn't drown.